# Libreoffice Calc Today Function Date Format?

Tags: libreoffice

Is there a way to make the TODAY() function display a date like: 27/5/2017? I have my native date format set to this in on Ubuntu, but I suppose it doesn't display dates in the system native format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TODAY()` function really just returns an integer value - the initial format that's applied depends on the time format associated with the application's default locale setting.

You can set the default format in LO by going to the **Tools** --> **Options** --> **Language settings - Language** dialog. Choose a locale that uses the DD/MM/YYYY format, such as *English (UK)* or *English (Ireland):

[image: LO Language setting]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the individual format for a cell with as 'DD/MM/YYYY', but there does not seem to be a way to do this globally.

[image: Format cell dialogue]